# SMS Schedular in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, sms

I know how to send sms programatically from Blackberry to others...

But i want to know how can we send an SMS from my application at specified time chosen by  user..

Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ApplicationManager.scheduleApplication()` to schedule your application to run, probably with an alternate entry point, and send out the messages.